# How to add new extention to magento connect?

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions

I have followed http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/packagingmagentoconnectextensions6%200.pdf steps add new extension.

when I'm trying to upload my new extension to magento connect its getting below error

```
Invalid or not allowed image file Mime-Type.
```

please help me to fix this.

Comment: You can follow this article: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/7_-_magento_connect/creating_magento_connect_extension_package
I think that you packaged wrong.

Comment: I followed as provided link by you. After create package i'm trying to upload Yyyyy_Xxxx-1.0.0.1.tgz file to magento  from my account.Still its getting same error message. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution finally.before upload the package i have upload screen shot of interface.That's the mistake i have done.